# how to retrieve all rows from a table starting from the n'th row

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to retrieve all rows from a table starting from the n'th row.

For example, if the table has 20 rows and `n=9`, I want to retrieve all elements Where the first part of the retrieved elements are the elements from 9 to 20 and the second part are form 1 to 8.

`[9,10,...,19,20,1,2,...,7,8]`.

At first,I thought that I can use 2 queries to do that using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` .

```
//retrieve the 2nd group
SELECT * FROM Tname WHERE 1 LIMIT (Tsize-n+1) OFFSET (n)
//retrieve the 1st group
SELECT * FROM Tname WHERE 1 LIMIT (n-1)
```

Where I calculate `Tsize-n+1`, `n` and `n-1` before, and after retrieving elements I combine the two arrays.

But I don't think that this is the optimal solution (I don't want to use more than one query. and calculating the number of elements in the table is consuming).

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: So you want it to be all results in special order?

Comment: Why don't you select all rows, read first n rows and read to the end after that?

Comment: did you try using `orderBy DESC`?

Comment: @Ahmad What a brilliant idea :D , I think that this would be the best answer!

Comment: @Yazan, this might be a little late  but take a look at my updated answer, one query to select all, php does the rest for with `krsort` to reverse sort order and `array_chunk` does the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a simple idea. Just select all rows, then read first n rows and finally read remaining rows to the end. Just that!

Comment: I thing that this is the best way to reduce the query time and execution! Just like I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use small trick to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM Tname ORDER BY id >= n DESC, id ASC
```

This way you have results in that order `[9,10,...,19,20,1,2,...,7,8]`.

If that didn't work (you don't know what id must be used as boundary) you can rearrange results in PHP:

```
$n = 9;
$resultsArray = array_merge(
    array_slice($resultsArray, $n), 
    array_slice($resultsArray, 0, $n)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this :

```
(SELECT * FROM  Tname WHERE id >= n)
UNION (SELECT * FROM  Tname WHERE id < n)
```

Answer (score 0):

just reverse order by any column and pass the offset and limit

```
$data = SELECT * FROM  table;
```

in php

```
krsort($data); 
$chunked_data = array_chunk($data,9);
```